# Changing the default :junk-allowed value of parse-integer from a top level function in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, keyword

I'm working in emacs with LISP and I've come across an error that I'm not sure how to get around.  I'll put up the output, what I understand from it and what I'm missing.

Error:

```
junk in string "(-5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6)"
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-PARSE-ERROR]


Backtrace:

0: (PARSE-INTEGER "(-5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6)" :START 0 :END NIL :RADIX 10 :JUNK-ALLOWED NIL)    
1: ((:METHOD CLSQL-SYS:READ-SQL-VALUE :AROUND (T T T T)) "(-5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6)" INTEGER #<CLSQL-SQLITE3:SQLITE3-DATABASE C:/Users/sas31/idyom/db/database.sqlite OPEN {1007D61933}> :SQLITE3) [fa..     
2: ((:METHOD CLSQL-SYS::UPDATE-SLOT-FROM-DB-VALUE (CLSQL-SYS:STANDARD-DB-OBJECT T T)) #<unavailable argument> #<unavailable argument> #<unavailable argument>) [fast-method]     
3: (CLSQL-SYS::BUILD-OBJECTS (#<CLSQL-SYS:SELECT-LIST {100592E993}>) #<unavailable argument> #<CLSQL-SQLITE3:SQLITE3-DATABASE C:/Users/sas31/idyom/db/database.sqlite OPEN {1007D61933}> #<unavailable argu..    
4: (CLSQL-SYS::FIND-ALL (IDYOM-DB:MTP-EVENT) :RESULT-TYPES :AUTO :REFRESH NIL :INSTANCES NIL :WHERE #<CLSQL-SYS:SQL-RELATIONAL-EXP (MTP_EVENT.COMPOSITION_ID = 0 AND MTP_EVENT.DATASET_ID = 26)> :FLATP T :..    
5: (CLSQL-SYS::FIND-ALL (IDYOM-DB:MTP-EVENT) :RESULT-TYPES :AUTO :REFRESH NIL :INSTANCES NIL :WHERE #<CLSQL-SYS:SQL-RELATIONAL-EXP (MTP_EVENT.COMPOSITION_ID = 0 AND MTP_EVENT.DATASET_ID = 26)> :FLATP T :..    
6: (CLSQL-SYS:SELECT IDYOM-DB:MTP-EVENT :WHERE #<CLSQL-SYS:SQL-RELATIONAL-EXP (MTP_EVENT.COMPOSITION_ID = 0 AND MTP_EVENT.DATASET_ID = 26)> :FLATP T :RESULT-TYPES NIL :DATABASE #<CLSQL-SQLITE3:SQLITE3-DA..    
7: (CLSQL-SYS::FAULT-JOIN-SLOT #<CLSQL-SYS::STANDARD-DB-CLASS IDYOM-DB:MTP-COMPOSITION> #<IDYOM-DB:MTP-COMPOSITION {10047AAA73}> #<CLSQL-SYS::VIEW-CLASS-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION IDYOM-DB::EVENTS>)    
8: ((:METHOD SB-MOP:SLOT-VALUE-USING-CLASS (CLSQL-SYS::STANDARD-DB-CLASS T T)) #<unavailable argument> #<unavailable argument> #<unavailable argument>) [fast-method]    
9: (IDYOM-DB::GET-EVENT-SEQUENCE 26 0)    
10: (IDYOM-DB:COUNT-EVENTS 26 0)    
11: (MIDI2DB::FIX-BIOI-DUR-DELTAST 26)    
12: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (MIDI2DB::FIX-BIOI-DUR-DELTAST 26) #<NULL-LEXENV>)    
13: (EVAL (MIDI2DB::FIX-BIOI-DUR-DELTAST 26))
```

So, I would like to change `:junk-allowed nil` to `t` in `parse-integer`, but I don't know how to do that because I'm not where when or why it's called.  The function `get-event-sequence` (written for this particular programme) calls `get-composition`, which reads as follows:

```
(defun get-composition (dataset-id composition-id)

 "Returns the composition whose dataset-id is <dataset-id> and whose
  composition-id is <composition-id>." 

 (car (clsql:select
        'mtp-composition
        :flatp t 
        :where [and [= [slot-value 'mtp-composition 'dataset-id] dataset-id]
                    [= [slot-value 'mtp-composition 'composition-id] composition-id]])))
```

I don't know where this parse-integer is being called from this function or how to change the value of that keyword.  Also, the string of numbers are coded key signatures and represent all the key signatures in this particular data set, but why is that important when this function only seems to deal with `dataset-id` and `composition-id`?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Even if you could specify a true value for junk-allowed, it still wouldn't make sense with input like `(-5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6)`. **parse-integer** is for parsing a *single* integer from a string, not a list of integers.

Comment: It seems a data error, either in the data inside the database (which is SQLite3, that *does not check* the type of the fields when data are inserted), or in the model definition of it (inside `clsql:def-view-class`, for instance). So I think the first thing to do is to look at the data of the database and see if in the relation(s) corresponding to `mtp-composition` there is some problem with the record (or the records) with `dataset-id` equal to 26 and `composition-id` equal to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the backtrace, we can see that `parse-integer` is called by a method on the generic function `clsql-sys:read-sql-value`.

It is not clear, without checking the code, if that `:junk-allowed nil` is just the backtrace showing you default values or if it's actively called that way from the method.

However, getting that set to a true value would not really help you, since the return value would be `nil` (because "(" is not a number or a white-space). This means that there's a deeper problem with your database, possibly due to an implicit schema violation (you've said "I want to store numbers", then stored a list of numbers and the ORM did something it cannot recover from).

```
* (parse-integer " 2 " :junk-allowed t)

2
2
*  (parse-integer "(2 " :junk-allowed t)

NIL
0
```